# Spring data JPA doesn't delete entity

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with deleting entity from database. Whatever I do anyway it doesn't delete.

**Driver class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "drivers")
public class Driver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "driver", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonSerialize(using = RatingsSerializer.class)
    private List<Rating> ratings;

    // other fields. Getters and Setters...
}
```

**Rating class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ratings")
@JsonDeserialize(using = RatingDeserializer.class)
public class Rating {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
    private Driver driver;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;
    private int mark;
    private Date createdAt;

    //Getters and Setters ...
}
```

First one what I do is annotate `ratings` with `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "driver", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)` and when call `driverRepository.delete(driver)` it throws:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "drivers" violates foreign key constraint "fk3raf3d9ucm571r485t8e7ew83" on table "ratings"

Ok, choose another way. Try to delete each rating object using `ratingRepository`, but never happens, it just iterate thorough each rating item and throw again error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

Next step was to set for each rating item **Client** and **Driver** to null. Now driver entity is deleted from database but rating entity remain in database.
What happens?

*Spring Data JPA* version: **1.5.7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that your Foreign Key error is related to Client table which is linked according to your code line:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
private Client client;
```

So, if you add cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE within the annotation, it may works. But, that' up to you if you want to delete everything on cascade including Client row. If not, then update that column value first to null.